# Oracle SQL - Convert a number value into real timestamp (time only - no date)

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, time, etl

I've a ETL process reading data from source which is Oracle database and includes a column of type number holding a timestamp (e.g. '131516' = 'HHMMSS').
In the target which is a postgres database the value should be written in a column of type 'time' expecting the format 'HH:MM:SS'.

I tried different converts with to_char, to_date and to_timestamp, but I don't get a suitable result.

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(131516, '000000'), 'hh24:mi:ss') from table
```

This returns unfortunately a timestamp with date, but will have only the time.

How do I get the numeric value as time in format 'HH:MM:SS'?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you run that SQL in Postgres or in Oracle? In Postgres you can simply cast it: `131516::text::time`

Comment: Which ETL process are you using?

Comment: I'm using Pentaho as ETL stack.

Comment: I know the ::text::time function is Postgres, but the source query is on Oracle.

Comment: If you just select `to_char(131516, '000000')` on the Oracle side, this should be directly insertable into a `time` column in Postgres. A time column accepts strings formatted as `hh24:mi:ss` just as well as strings formatted as `hh24miss`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the numeric value to PostgreSQL in your ETL.  There are no colon (`:`) characters in the result of `to_char(131516, '000000')`, so do not include them in the format mask.

After you convert it to a `timestamp`, cast the value to `time`:

```
select to_timestamp(to_char(131516, '000000'), 'HH24MISS')::time;

 to_timestamp 
--------------
 13:15:16
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm using Pentaho as ETL stack where the value in the output step to Postgres must be already converted to type 'time'.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below casting function in your source query of the ETL process,

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp('131516', 'hh24miss'), 'hh24:mi:ss') from table;
```

demo
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5b890d21c0c27ea7be3ac4b42ad813d1

Comment: This returns for my column: Inconsistent data types: - expected, NUMBER received.

Comment: And I don't want to have a string value as result.